# SML/NJ: getting user input

Tags: user-input, sml, smlnj

How do I prompt for user input while a function is running?

Answer (score 5):

To read a line from standard input use [TextIO.inputLine](http://sml-family.org/Basis/text-io.html#SIG:TEXT_IO.inputLine:VAL) from the [Standard Basis Library](http://sml-family.org/Basis/toc.html), I think you can just do something like

```
TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn
```

Clarification: this returns a `string option` type, which is NONE if it is at EOF

Comment: You might need to valOf the result, as TextIO.inputLine returns a string option.

Answer (score 5):

My code looks something like this:

```
fun get infile = ( TextIO.output(TextIO.stdOut, prompt)
                 ; TextIO.flushOut(TextIO.stdOut)
                 ; TextIO.inputLine infile
                 )
```

This returns a value of type `string option`; normally a line `SOME l`, but `NONE` on end of file.